# GetComputerName WinApi call and %COMPUTERNAME% environment variable

Tags: windows, winapi

Does the WinAPI call GetComputerName and reading %COMPUTERNAME% environment variable ALWAYS return the same result on Windows?

Comment: You probably heard before that using global variables in a program is bad.  Environment variables are bad squared, their value can be randomly different even without your code setting the value.  Not to speak of the nastiness of them being strings and whatever code sets them very rarely being aware of proper text encoding.  They should have stayed in Unix :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee that these two things are the same. For example, a program could change or even delete the environment variable. It would be somewhat perverse for a program to do that, but is technically possible.